# I can't get my jQuery to work and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I'm really new at all of this stuff and I'm a little stuck. I've been working on this project but for some reason I can't get my jQuery to load no matter what I do.

here's my HTML

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Eerbivore</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="gal.css">
<script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="gal.js"></script>
```

jQuery

```
$('#gallery').flickity({
    cellAlign: 'center',
    wrapAround: true
});
```

I'm using Brackets as my editor. Any help or anything thing I should add would be very helpful.

Comment: There is two jquery core included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is here, you included more than one of jquery core library.

```
//<--- remove any of this
<script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

And for this code, it is better if you put inside document.ready.**(Ignore if already done this part)**

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $('#gallery').flickity({
     cellAlign: 'center',
     wrapAround: true
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

as the others mentioned, only include one library of jquery,
also worth mentioning that `.flickity()` is not native in jquery and the code for that should be included aswell.